# JBPM 6.1.0 Deployment Error

Tags: mysql, jboss, installation, jbpm

I have JBPM 6.0.1 up and running with mysql no problem. I have decided to upgrade to 6.1.0. When I run the installer (ant install.demo) with the latest release the deployment fails every time. 
Somehow the h2 driver is now interfering with the deployment (maybe). Any help with this guys...
The server log error is below...

```
2014-09-01 04:37:25,422 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jbpm-console.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
"Services that were unable to start:" => [
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".CdiValidatorFactoryService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".WeldStartService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.AvailableJobsExecutor.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.AvailableJobsExecutor.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.AvailableJobsExecutor.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.ConfigServiceWatchServiceExecutorImpl.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.ConfigServiceWatchServiceExecutorImpl.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.ConfigServiceWatchServiceExecutorImpl.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.IOWatchServiceExecutorImpl.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.IOWatchServiceExecutorImpl.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.IOWatchServiceExecutorImpl.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.IncrementalBuilderExecutorManager.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.IncrementalBuilderExecutorManager.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.IncrementalBuilderExecutorManager.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.JMSAuditProcessor.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.JMSAuditProcessor.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.JMSAuditProcessor.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.KieSessionRequesMessageBean.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.KieSessionRequesMessageBean.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.KieSessionRequesMessageBean.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.MailboxProcessOutgoingExecutorManager.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.MailboxProcessOutgoingExecutorManager.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.MailboxProcessOutgoingExecutorManager.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.RetryTrackerSingleton.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.RetryTrackerSingleton.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.RetryTrackerSingleton.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.SimpleAsyncExecutorService.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.SimpleAsyncExecutorService.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.SimpleAsyncExecutorService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.TaskServiceRequesMessageBean.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.TaskServiceRequesMessageBean.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.TaskServiceRequesMessageBean.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.WebSphereRoleProviderServices.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.WebSphereRoleProviderServices.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.WebSphereRoleProviderServices.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.BundleTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.BundleTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatCurrencyTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatCurrencyTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatDateTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatDateTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatDateTimeTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatDateTimeTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatNumberTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatNumberTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatPercentTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatPercentTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatStringTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatStringTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatTimeTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.FormatTimeTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.IfdefTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.IfdefTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.IfndefTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.IfndefTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.LocaleTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.LocaleTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.MessageArgumentTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.MessageArgumentTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.MessageTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.i18n.MessageTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.CatchTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.CatchTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ChooseTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ChooseTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.OtherwiseTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.OtherwiseTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.RemoveTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.RemoveTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ForEachTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ForEachTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.IfTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.IfTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.SetTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.SetTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.WhenTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.WhenTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ForEachTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ForEachTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ForTokensTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ForTokensTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.IfTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.IfTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ImportTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ImportTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.OutTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.OutTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ParamTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ParamTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.RedirectTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.RedirectTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.SetTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.SetTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.UrlTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.UrlTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.BundleTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.BundleTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.FormatDateTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.FormatDateTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.FormatNumberTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.FormatNumberTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.MessageTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.MessageTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParamTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParamTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseDateTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseDateTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseNumberTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseNumberTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.RequestEncodingTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.RequestEncodingTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetBundleTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetBundleTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetLocaleTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetLocaleTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.TimeZoneTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.TimeZoneTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.DateParamTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.DateParamTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.ParamTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.ParamTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.QueryTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.QueryTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.SetDataSourceTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.SetDataSourceTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.TransactionTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.TransactionTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.uberfire.server.FileDownloadServlet\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.uberfire.server.FileDownloadServlet\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.uberfire.server.FileUploadServlet\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.uberfire.server.FileUploadServlet\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.uberfire.server.UberfireServlet\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".component.\"org.uberfire.server.UberfireServlet\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".deploymentCompleteService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".jndiDependencyService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.module.jbpm-console.jbpm-console.DefaultDataSource",
    "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./jbpm-console",
    "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./jbpm-console.UndertowDeploymentInfoService"
],
"Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.h2"]
}}

2014-09-01 04:37:26,452 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("data-source" => "ExampleDS")
```

]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.h2]",
    "jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.h2]"
]}
2014-09-01 04:37:26,470 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "ExampleDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.h2]",
        "jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.h2]"
    ],
    "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
            "jboss.data-source.reference-factory.ExampleDS",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS"
        ],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.h2"]
    }
}

Comment: You need to remove reference of ExampleDS from `standalone.xml`. If it will not resolve then add `standalone.xml` here.

Answer (score 0):

Check why

```
"Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.h2"]
2014-09-01 04:37:26,452 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([ ("subsystem" => "datasources"), ("data-source" => "ExampleDS")
```

cannot be deployed

Comment: thats the problem, why is it using h2 in the first place... i have disabled it in persistence.xml file and changed to mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Right I got it working...

In the standalone xml file I changed the h2 eaxmpleDB to the same connection url as the sql one. I also changed the driver to MySQL.

This should be mentioned on their documentation but the JBOSS site says to just ignore it when intact you must change it...

Hope that helps someone...